# Sort an Elastic Search query by the date difference of a nested object

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I've got two entities, a `file` with child `tasks`. Here's an example json with 2 rows:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "file1",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "targetDate": "2023-06-01"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "targetDate": "2020-07-01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "file2",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "targetDate": "2022-06-01"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "targetDate": "2023-06-27"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to sort these results by the task which is closest to today's date. So the result would have `file2` on top, because it contains a task with date `2023-06-27`, which is closest to today.

As SQL, something like this:

```
SELECT f.id, f.name,
       DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, MIN(t.target_date)) AS date_difference
FROM files f
INNER JOIN tasks t on t.file_id = f.id
GROUP BY f.id
ORDER BY date_difference DESC
```

The goal is to get this working in Symfony's FOSElasticaBundle, but I'd be happy with an example in a plain ElasticSearch search request as well.

I've been looking at script examples and things like aggregation and nested sorts, but I've got no clue how to structure this..any help appreciated.

EDIT:
I've got a script that can calculate the datedifference now, but sorting is not allowed on `script_fields`..Now trying to get the logic in a sort script, but running into problems with nested fields. Current script:

```
{
  "sort": [
      {
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "order": "desc",
            "nested": {
                "path": "taken",
                "script": {}
            }
        }
      }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "taken",
            "inner_hits": {
                "script_fields": {
                    "diff_dates": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(params.current_date); ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of('Z')); return doc['taken.targetDate'].value.until(now, ChronoUnit.DAYS);",       
                            "params": {
                                "current_date": 1688031608000
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "script": {
                      "script": "doc['taken.status'].value != 'Open'"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey Oli, I updated my answer so you do not have to update the mapping ^^

Comment: Thanks! no worries, that was just example input anyhow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

You will not be able to access `nested fields` using script in elasticsearch.

You may want to change the mapping to allow to have access to it.

Although you can use the `_source` to read from. This will need your query to read from the source, which can be slower than just accessing fields.

## Solution

## with the nested mapping

#### set up

```json
PUT 76574308_nested
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "tasks": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "targetDate": {
            "type": "date"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /76574308_nested/_doc/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "file1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "targetDate": "2023-06-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "targetDate": "2020-07-01"
    }
  ]
}

PUT /76574308_nested/_doc/2
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "file2",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "targetDate": "2022-06-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "targetDate": "2023-06-27"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Query with runtime fields and _source

```json
GET 76574308_nested/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "diff_date": {
      "type": "long",
      "script": {
        "source": """
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(new Date().getTime()),
                                          ZoneId.systemDefault());
        ArrayList dates = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < params['_source']['tasks'].length; i++ ){
          dates.add((LocalDate.parse(params['_source']['tasks'][i]['targetDate'], DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
        }
        

        ZonedDateTime latest = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
        Instant.ofEpochMilli(dates.stream().map(e -> e.toInstant().toEpochMilli()).min(Long::compare).get()),ZoneId.systemDefault());
        
        
        long delta = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(latest, now);
        
        emit(delta);"""
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "diff_date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

## With a new mapping

Here is a pet project sorting document based on the delta with the actual time.

The script find the oldest document in task, and compute the delta with the actual time.

Then it sort the results based on this delta.

#### Set up

```json
PUT /76574308/_doc/1
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "file1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "targetDate": "2023-06-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "targetDate": "2020-07-01"
    }
  ]
}

PUT /76574308/_doc/2
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "file2",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "targetDate": "2022-06-01"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "targetDate": "2023-06-27"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Query with runtime fields

```json
GET 76574308/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "diff_date": {
      "type": "long",
      "script": {
        "source": """
        ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(new Date().getTime()),
                                          ZoneId.systemDefault());
        # Get all tasks dates
        ArrayList dates = new ArrayList();
        for(int i = 0; i < doc['tasks.targetDate'].length; i++ ){
          dates.add(doc['tasks.targetDate'][i]);
        }
        
        # Get latest date
        ZonedDateTime latest = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
        Instant.ofEpochMilli(dates.stream().map(e -> e.toInstant().toEpochMilli()).min(Long::compare).get()),ZoneId.systemDefault());
        
        
        long delta = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(latest, now);
        
        emit(delta);"""
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "diff_date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

which gives:

```json
{
...
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 2,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [
      {
        ...
        "_source": {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "file1",
          ...
        },
        "sort": [
          1097
        ]
      },
      {
        ...
        "_source": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "file2",
          ...
        },
        "sort": [
          397
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```